# Reflect caching java, como fazer?

Tags: java, reflexão

Se eu posso instanciar um novo objeto com reflection, como eu posso fazer caching para o tipo que ele pertencente? `newInstance()` retorna um tipo `Object` mas preciso do objeto primário, que posso pegar o tipo pelo nome.

Mas quero lidar com isto de outra forma.

Traduzindo. Quero pegar através do nome da classe usar a classe normalmente.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("br.com.macadu.aprendizado.testando.T3");
Object newInstance = clazz.newInstance();
log.info(newInstance.getClass().toString());
for (Field field : newInstance.getClass().getFields()) {
    log.info(field.toString());
}
```

Como surgiu duvida sobre a pergunta. O que eu quero é instanciar uma classe via reflection e retornar um objeto do tipo que o objeto é. Não do tipo Object como alguns acreditaram ser.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer dizer por "*caching para o tipo que ele percente*". Você já tem o objeto `clazz`, e ele representa o tipo. Além disso, o método `Class.newInstance()` foi considerado *deprecated* no Java 9. Utilize `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()` no lugar.

Comment: Porque você faz `newInstance.getClass()` ao invés de usar `clazz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez o que você queira seja apenas isso:

```
T3 newInstance = T3.class.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Nesse código, `T3.class` é um objeto do tipo `Class<T3>`. A partir dele, você pode criar instâncias. Esse código supõe que `T3` tenha uma construtor sem parâmetros.

Vamos supor que `T4`, por outro lado, tem um construtor com um parâmetro do tipo `String`. Nesse caso:

```
T4 newInstance = T4.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("Teste");
```

Os parâmetros do `getConstructor(...)` correspondem aos tipos dos parâmetros do construtor desejado, enquanto que os do `newInstance(...)` são os valores propriamente ditos.

Você pode usar o `Class.forName(String)` para obter a classe pelo nome. Mas isso vai dar um código assim:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("br.com.macadu.aprendizado.testando.T3");
Object instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Isso é particularmente muito útil para você instanciar classes apenas pelo nome dela sem saber exatamente que classe é essa, tal como quando você tem um nome de classe dado pelo usuário, lido de um arquivo, ou coisa assim. Mas a desvantagem é que como nesses casos, a classe instanciada pode ser qualquer coisa, o único tipo comum que você tem é `Object`.

Você até poderia fazer isso:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("br.com.macadu.aprendizado.testando.T3");
T3 instance = (T3) clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Mas, isso não tem muito sentido, afinal ela não têm muita vantagem sobre o `T3.class.getConstructor().newInstance();`.

Quando você quer instanciar subclasses ou implementadores de uma interface, isso fica mais interessante:

```
String implementacao = "com.example.ClasseQueImplementaMinhaInterface";
Class<? extends MinhaInterface> clazz = Class.forName(implementacao)
        .asSubclass(MinhaInterface.class);
MinhaInterface instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Usar o [método `newInstance()` da classe `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) pode parecer que seria mais fácil, mas ele foi marcado como *deprecated* desde o Java 9 devido ao fato de esse método não se comportar bem no caso de o construtor lançar uma exceção. Além disso, ele só funciona para construtores públicos sem parâmetros.

Por fim, se o construtor que você quer acessar não é público, use `getDeclaredConstructor(...)` ao invés de `getConstructor(...)`. Use também o `setAccessible(true)` para garantir permissão de acesso mesmo se a classe não for pública e estiver em algum outro pacote.

```
String implementacao = "com.example.MaisOutraClasseQueImplementaMinhaInterface";
Class<? extends MinhaInterface> clazz = Class.forName(implementacao)
        .asSubclass(MinhaInterface.class);
Constructor<? extends MinhaInterface> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
ctor.setAccessible(true);
MinhaInterface instance = ctor.newInstance("Teste");
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi direito a sua pergunta, basta fazer isso:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("br.com.macadu.aprendizado.testando.T3");
log.info(clazz.toString());
for (Field field : clazz.getFields()) {
    log.info(field.toString());
}
```

Você não precisa criar uma instância da classe se a única coisa que te interessa é o objeto `Class`.

Além disso, o [método `newInstance()` da classe `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) foi marcado como *deprecated* desde o Java 9 devido ao fato de esse método não se comportar bem no caso de o construtor lançar uma exceção. Assim sendo, ao invés disso:

```
Object newInstance = clazz.newInstance();
```

Use isso:

```
Object newInstance = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Ou se preferir (e tiver certeza que o construtor é público), use isso:

```
Object newInstance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente a pergunta dele, mas acho que ele quer implementar uma espécie de *Singleton* via *reflection*. Ele quer que na primeira chamada crie o objeto, e, nas seguintes, essa mesma instância seja retornada.

Comment: @FelipeMarinho Se for isso, usar um `Map<Class<?>, Object>` poderia resolver. Mas, acabei achando melhor dar um voto de fechamento na pergunta como "*não está clara o suficiente*", porque realmente, está difícil entender o que está sendo pedido.

Comment: Agora que ele editou a pergunta ficou mais claro. Ele quer fazer o *casting* do objeto, e não o *caching*.